How to modify HTML file and open it with browser using robotframework?
i’m working on a scenario with Robot Framework where I need to modify three values in an HTML file and then execute it using Chrome. However, I’m struggling to find information on how to achieve this, especially since I'm familiar with loading JSON and XML files but can't find a way to load HTML files.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
Here’s the content of the HTML file:
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The Title</title>
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
</head>
 
<body>
  <form id="formulaire" method="post" action="Variable1"> 
  <input type="hidden" id="PaReq" name="PaReq" value="Variable2"/>   
  <input type="hidden" id="TermUrl" name="TermUrl" value="Variable3"/>   
  <input type="hidden" id="MD" name="MD" value=""/>   
</form>
 
<script>
    document.forms[0].submit();
</script>
</body>
</html>


Not sure how good this works but here is one way:
Read the html file using python. Then use python regex to find and replace the desired values. Save the file.
Now use robot framework to call the html file (open browser    desiredbrowser   url).
Hope this works!

one usually does not modify the html, you interact with the given html via browser.  Your options are either SeleniumLibrary or Browser

Well i was looking for library or a pre-defined method to do it but nothing was found,
so i made a simple python script that i use later in a robotframework keyword,
here is the code
# update_html.py
import os
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def update_html(file_path, new_action, new_pareq_value, new_termurl_value):
    file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates', 'acs.html')
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser')

    form = soup.find('form')
    form['action'] = new_action

    pareq_input = soup.find('input', {'id': 'PaReq'})
    pareq_input['value'] = new_pareq_value

    termurl_input = soup.find('input', {'id': 'TermUrl'})
    termurl_input['value'] = new_termurl_value

    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(str(soup))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Vérifier si le bon nombre d'arguments a été fourni
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print("Usage: python update_html.py <new_action> <new_pareq_value> <new_termurl_value>")
        sys.exit(1)

    new_action = sys.argv[1]
    new_pareq_value = sys.argv[2]
    new_termurl_value = sys.argv[3]

    update_html('acs.html', new_action, new_pareq_value, new_termurl_value)

And for execute it, i added a library Process
then i used
Run Process    python3    ${script_path}    ${paReq}    ${termUrl}    ${redirectionUrl}
